# using library to replace column values in python

Tags: python, pandas, mapping

I am trying to replace the FIPS code with state abbreviations using us library. This is how I can get the value for each individual state

```
fips_name = us.states.mapping('fips', 'name')
fips_name['20']
Out[31]: 'Kansas'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assming that `fips_name` is a dictionary of `fips -> state names`, you can use the `.map` method of a `pandas.Series` (column):

```
df["state_names"] = df["fips"].map(fips_name)
```

Update w/ working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import us

df = pd.DataFrame({"fips": ["01", "01", "08", "09", "10", "06"]})
fips_to_name = us.states.mapping("fips", "name")

df["states"] = df["fips"].map(fips_to_name)

print(df)
  fips       states
0   01      Alabama
1   01      Alabama
2   08     Colorado
3   09  Connecticut
4   10     Delaware
5   06   California
```

Comment: Sorry should have clarified, my variable `df` in this case is the `pandas.DataFrame` object that contains a column of fips codes (in this case `df["fips"]` returns the column of fips codes). If possible, can you provide an example of your dataset (first 5 rows should be fine), as well as the entire contents of `fips_name`?